# How to monitor incoming and outgoing internet connections

Tags: macos, network-programming

I mean how to measure all internet traffic taking place on my machine in objective-c.

Comment: would you like to measure the traffic for your application or the entire system's traffic ?

Answer (score 1):

There's no Cocoa API to do this. You'll need to user lower-level (BSD layer) APIs.

Comment: Thank you @Chris, @Moszi i'd like to measure entire system's traffic.